# How to publish metadata-binary to Broker database?

Tags: content-manager, broker, database, binary

We have a Page Metadata Schema where editors can embed a Multimedia Component.

When we publish the Page to the Broker database, it seems that the binary is not published to the database (TCM id is not in the Binary, BinaryContents, ... tables).

Do we need to add a specific Template Building Block in our Template Builder to the Page Template to get this functionality?

Any suggestions whatsoever?

Kind regards,
Herman

Comment: If we add an image to the contents of a component, place the component on a page and publish the page, the image binay comes into the database correctly. But if we add the image to the metadata of a page (embedded metadata field), it doesn't get published to the database... Any idea? Kind regards,
Herman

Comment: Please use the edit function to provide more information instead of adding additional answers.
If you wish the image to also show up on the page, then use the first approach from my answer. If not, you can go with the second approach using the `AddBinary()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Does the actual content of the binary end up anywhere? Or is the question purely about some metadata information in the broker tables? 
If you want to have the actual binary content in the database, then you must configure the storage config for that item type accordingly.

In either case, to have the binary processed, you need to reference it in your Templating code. Some of the methods are:

- DWT with `<img src="tcm of the binary component"...>`
- C#, by using the `AddBinary()` method, make sure you use the appropriate overload so you don't end up with unmanaged binaries, take a look at [HERE](https://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/which-addbinary-not-to-use.html)
- DD4T/DXA templates

In combination with the 'Publish binaries in package' TBB from the 'Default finish action' compound TBB.

Once the binary itself is published, the metadata (for the various broker tables) goes along with it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your issue, it looks like

- In the `storage_conf.xml`, Binary & its metadata is configured or defaulted to file system. That the reason, you may not be seeing in the broker db. Verify in the configured file system.
- You haven't called **AddBinary()** method in your templating project. Due to that, no binary is available in the transport package and no entries in db as well.